# List all records in parse's join table

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I made a list in table view controller. By getting data from 2 parse objects "trip" and "User". Now I can get data from "trip" but I can't get the profile pic from "User".

```
var innerQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Trip")
var teamQuery = PFUser.query()

innerQuery.whereKey("user" , notEqualTo: PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName:"_User", objectId:""))
```

This error appears:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

On this line:

```
travelingDetail += sweet.objectForKey("username") as String
```

Comment: have you checked whether sweet is nil?

Comment: no its not nil @rshankar

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "user" is an attribute of Trip, I am guessing of type PFUser? If that is the case and you want to access the attributes of the PFUser object in a Trip object that you queried, then you will need to include that attribute before you perform the query.  Something like teamQuery.include("user")